# pyspark json to dataframe schema

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, pyspark-schema

i have tricky json which i would like to load into a dataframe and need assistance on how i may be able to define a schema

```
{
    "1-john": {
        "children": ["jack", "jane", "jim"]
    },
    "2-chris": {
        "children": ["bill", "will"]
    }
}
```

dataframe output needed

| ID | father | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | ["jack", "jane", "jim"] |
| 2 | chris | ["bill", "will"] |

Comment: Pyspark df or Pandas df?

Comment: would prefer a pyspark df

Answer (score 0):

In the case of pandas, Use:

```
import json
t = json.dumps(d)
df = pd.read_json(t, orient = 'index')
ids = df.reset_index()['index'].str.split('-').str[0]
fathers = df.reset_index()['index'].str.split('-').str[1]
df['ID']=ids
df['fathers'] = fathers
```

You can then convert this to pyspark df:

```
df_sp = spark_session.createDataFrame(df)
```